# Counter Staining with Safranin

Tags: microbiology

After Gram Staining,
We use counter staining to find out that is there any gram(-) bacteria present on the prepared slide.

My question is-

**What component in the cell wall of gram(-) bacteria is responsible for the retention of Safranin dye?**
Like the Techoic Acid is responsible for the retention of CVI complex in gram (+) bacteria.

As I have just studied the staining process,any additional useful information is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it hard to find actual literature on this, so this is just my reasoning. Safranin is a basic dye (ie positively charged). I suspect electrostatic interactions with negative charges on phospholipids in the inner membrane are responsible for its retention.

Comment: @canadianer- thanks! Your explanation helped a lot. If you can find any literature related to this, can you please post it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Safranin is retained, very much like Crystal violet, by the **peptidoglycans** in the cell wall. However, the main difference is the thickness of the **peptidoglycan** layers in *Gram positive* and *Gram negative* bacteria.

*Gram positive* bacteria, due to their thicker **peptidoglycan** layer, have a higher affinity to and retention rate of crystal violet. On the other hand, *Gram negative* bacteria, due to a thinner **peptidoglycan** layer cannot retain crystal violet as well and are more likely to retain safranin.